# align property in css

Tags: css

I have the below html.What I am trying to do is center the contents of the p tag.The thing is that if I do a align on the div then it works but when I do it in the p tag it does not.Not good with css and want quick solution so asking u guys for help.

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p align="center" style="width:500px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor neque augue. Mauris a ante et libero tincidunt lacinia. Donec at lorem eu mi sagittis pretium. Donec sed ligula vel nunc placerat auctor quis vitae est. Nullam varius leo sed elit auctor rutrum. Pellentesque at erat quis nibh eleifend tincidunt sed feugiat est. Fusce dolor ante, imperdiet in congue ut, vulputate vitae nisi. Vivamus hendrerit felis a leo laoreet eget mollis purus tempus. Etiam fringilla est lacus. Praesent quis purus sem. Vestibulum interdum scelerisque consectetur. Nam nulla est, lacinia in eleifend eget, ultricies at est. Phasellus congue sollicitudin tellus, sit amet lobortis odio interdum et. Quisque turpis elit, feugiat in laoreet mollis, tempus et leo. Morbi eget viverra enim. Donec nec lacus dolor. Suspendisse tincidunt mi in enim gravida et fringilla lacus ultrices. Integer ac augue at nulla sollicitudin placerat. Morbi et ligula quis mauris consequat egestas vel et sapien. Ut ut justo a augue ullamcorper egestas ullamcorper vel nisl. Cras quam ligula, pharetra at pulvinar et, scelerisque vel erat. Donec scelerisque metus vitae libero accumsan quis suscipit urna pretium. Curabitur imperdiet, turpis a pulvinar adipiscing, nibh felis fringilla felis, nec consequat felis justo accumsan est.</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe `<p style="width:500px;margin:auto">' will work?

Comment: Are you trying to center the paragraph itself or the text within?  If you want to align the text, use text-align: center;

Comment: I was trying to center the paragraph itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align` is a [deprecated attribute](http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html) in HTML 5 .. instead give the `<p>` an explicit width and add:

`margin: 0 auto;` to center the entire element (top/bottom 0, left/right auto)

or

`text-align: center;` to center the elements text

Comment: This centers the paragraph tag itself, OP wants to center the contents of P.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the property align is [meant for divs](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_div_align.asp). Also, it is deprecated, there are better ways to style your paragraphs than that.

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBfbk/)** example.

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width:100%;
}

p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>        
</div>
```

Comment: -1.  Correct about deprecation, but you should give him a better way.

Comment: I have created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dG6Ck/ ..I tried using your solution in simple div and p and it works..Can you look at my example and see what is wrong over there.

Answer (score 1):

Text is center aligned. I have tested it in latest IE, Chrome and Firefox.

You can try `<p style="width:500px; text-align:center">`

Comment: The OP wants to align the block of text, not the text.

Comment: @AleksG "What I am trying to do is center the contents of the p tag"

That means he is centering the text itself not the paragraph itself.

Comment: If you read the code in the question, he's trying to achieve the equivalent of `align="center"`, which means aligning the block, not the text.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked your problem, and actually the text is centered in your p tag. I think you are trying to move your p tag in the center of the div,
and you can achieve that by

```
p
{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

here is also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/3r7J8/)

just an advice: a good practice is to separate your styles from your html, so move all your styling to a separate style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<p style="width:500px;margin:auto">...</p>
```